# Open GLES 1.1 - GLColorPointer creates a rainbow of colours when I just want red

Tags: opengl-es, colors

I'm rendering an object like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < COLOR_ARRAY_SIZE; i += 4) {
    colors[i] = 1.0f;
    colors[i + 1] = 0.0f;
    colors[i + 2] = 0.0f;
    colors[i + 3] = 1.0f;
}

// Clear color and depth buffer
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Set GL11 flags:
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

// make sure nothing messes with the colour
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_DITHER);
glDisable(GL_FOG);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

// Load projection matrix:
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(projectionMatrix);

// Load model view matrix and scale appropriately
int kObjectScale = 300f;
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(modelViewMatrix);
glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
glScalef(kObjectScale, kObjectScale, kObjectScale);

// Draw object
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (const GLvoid*) &vertexPositions[0]);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (const GLvoid*) &vertexNormals[0]);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, (const GLvoid*) &colors[0]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 11733, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
        (const GLvoid*) &indices[0]);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

I would expect that this would render my object all in red, but instead it's a rainbow of different colours. Does anyone know why? I would assume that there is something wrong with my "colors" array buffer but I can't for the life of me see what it is. The actual vertices seem to rendered just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is very confused. You're incrementing your value of i by 4 each time. What's more is that you're indexing with an offset of 1, 2 and 3 in lines 3-5. I presume that your define of COLOR_ARRAY_SIZE is 4? Try initializing your color array as follows:

`float colors[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};`

And then calling glColorPointer as follows:

`glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);`

Notice that I've set the stride to be 0. If your color array only contains colors then I don't see any reason why you should be using a stride (stride is used to jump over interwoven information in an array).

Comment: I accidentally set the stride to 1 whilst experimenting and forgot to change it before posting, sorry - I'll change that. I'm filling the colors array in that manner so that I get a buffer of R,G,B,A values that represent red for each vertex. I'm doing this so that I can debug why my colours are a mess. Eventually I want to swap out this "red" buffer for my real colors array. COLOR_ARRAY_SIZE == 15644.

Comment: Should that work? I changed the stride back to 0 and am still getting the multi-colour effect. Surely filling my array with 1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0 would get me red for each vertex?

Comment: If you've edited the code you posted in your question then the for loop still looks very dodgy to me! Why are you incrementing by 4 each time and then indexing your array with an offset? Have you tried declaring your array as I've suggested?

Comment: I did try setting it up as you suggested, but the app just crashed on me, presumably because there were more vertices than the "colors" array could supply.

Comment: When I filled the array with all 1.0f values it turned out all white, so I need something that'll be a different colour. I don't know how else to fill an array continuously with 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f ?

I'm now looking at using Open GL ES 2.0 and things seem to be going better (I was initially scared off with the do-your-own-lighting bit). Thanks for you help, though.

Comment: Ahhh I see sorry of course! I forgot that you'd need a color for each vertex in the array! Yea your for loop looks right to me. By the way I don't think it'll make a difference but you can just pass a pointer to the array as: `colors` instead of `&colors[0]`. Sorry I'm not sure what else.